# I can't reformat a USB drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, format

So I made a persistent Live USB of Ubuntu and while an apt upgrade was running, the computer froze. I waited 10 minutes and it was still frozen so I decided to force shutdown.

When I tried to boot up from the drive again, I noticed that it couldn't because some of the stuff on it became corrupt.I booted back into my real computer and tried to use gparted, disks, dd, and even tried reformating using a mac and windows but no success.

To be more specific:

Using Gparted, I tried to delete all the partitions and hit ok so there was no partitions, and I tried to reformat the partitions. When it is plugged into the linux box, all of the partitions are unmounted. When I try and hit okay, gparted will either say it worked (but go back to what it was before) or say that i couldnt make new partitions because they would be overlapping (that even happend when i just tried to make one partition.) Often when using the gparted method, i would hit okay and close gparted and restart it but it wouldnt respond to opening until i logged out, rebooted, or removed the drive.

Using dd, i attempted to reimage it with another iso. It didnt work. I also tried to write over it using an in file of /dev/zero. I let that sit for the whole night and I woke up and it was still going. No success with dd.

Then i tried the application drive to delete partitions and when i hit delete on a partition, the program would stop respoonding.

So i then went over to osx. I tried using disk utility to reformat it but one partition was mounting itself automatically and wouldnt unmount. When i treid it again, disk utility crashed and wouldnt even reopen while the drive was plugged in.

I unplugged, restarted and whent to osx terminal. I needed to unmount before i could do anything so i used diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2 and diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk2 (i also tried to just unmount the single partition that was mounted).

I also tried diskutil umount force and diskutil umount but had the same issue.

I went to another mac that had a more updated operating system. No Success.

So then I went to windows and tried to use the disk manager and it tells me i need to format the usb so i hit format and it was unsussesfull. Then i try to delete the partitions using the dissk manager and it says it deleted but nothing happned.

WHAT DO I DO!!

Comment: In gparted have you tried to create a new partition Table? (Its under the devices tab, choose msdos)

Comment: @jeroen, when i do that, gparted stops responding

Comment: and to be clear, I have never had issues with things not responding. I think the fact that programs haven't been responding across multiple OSs has to do with the drive

Comment: Yes I'm afraid you are right.

Comment: Since windows seems to be the only one that didn't freeze/hang try using the diskpart utility in windows. It's a command line tool.